# Python Compare Data Tables

Tags: python, datatable, compare

I am making a project where I need to compare data from python with data from excel or txt file. I will try to explain better: I web scraped a data table from a website (data table with 7 rows and 1 column), and I need to compare the values with a txt or excel file. This txt or excel file have a data table with 3 values that exist in the web scraped data table (3 rows and 1 column).

Web scraped data table:

```
FT 202003/69362
FT 202003/62581
FT 202003/41307
FT 202003/32316
FT 202003/4664
FT 201903/215090
FT 201903/197043
```

Data table in txt file or excel file

```
FT 202003/62581
FT 202003/41307
FT 202003/32316
```

My code so far:

```
faturas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='text-description-small']//b[contains(text(),'FT')]")
    totalfaturas = len(faturas)
    fat_list = []
    for fat in faturas:
        fat_list.append(fat.text)
        print(fat.text)
```

The objective is to find which values from web scraped data table don't exist in file data table, because all the values from data table have an associated button in this website, bu I just want to click the button from the values that don't exist in txt or excel file (this part I think I can do it). Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can use even strings `if "FT 202003/69362" in "FT 202003/62581\nFT 202003/41307\nFT 202003/32316":` - ie. `if fat.text in text_from_file:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use even `in` to check one text in another text:

```
text_from_file = '''FT 202003/62581
FT 202003/41307
FT 202003/32316'''

fat_text = 'FT 202003/62581'

if fat_text in text_from_file:
    print('already in file')
else:
    print('new element')
```

---

The same when you will have text from file as list of items

```
list_from_file = [
    'FT 202003/62581',
    'FT 202003/41307',
    'FT 202003/32316',
]    

fat_text = 'FT 202003/62581'

if fat_text in list_from_file:
    print('already in file')
else:
    print('new element')
```

---

For `pandas.DataFrame` you can use `

```
if any(df['items'] == fat_text):
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'items': [
    'FT 202003/62581',
    'FT 202003/41307',
    'FT 202003/32316',
]})

fat_text = 'FT 202003/62581'

if any(df['items'] == fat_text):
    print('already in file')
else:
    print('new element')
```

Eventually you can use sum() which convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`

```
if sum(df['items'] == fat_text) > 0:
```

or filter rows and check how many rows you get

```
if len(df[ df['items'] == fat_text ]) > 0:
```